# Image to pixel array in python

Tags: python, image, performance, jpeg

**Info:** I have 30,000 jpg images that I need to convert into (NumPy) pixel arrays.

**Problem:** I have tried using Pillow to do the image conversions but it does about 2 images a second which would take hours to complete.

```
from PIL import Image

for img_num in range(30_000):
   img = Image.open(img_dir+img_num+extension)
   img_list.append(np.array(img))
```

**Question:** What is the best and fastest way to convert a large number of jpg images to pixel arrays using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is taking the longest is the `append()` function.

Also, you are appending 30000 images to `img_list`, this means this single variable is extremely heavy in memory, do you actually need it? (if you image had 1000 pixels, you'd already be trying to allocate more than 30Mb)

In `PIL` and `openCV` the `read or`open` functions directly make them jumpy arrays.

Comment: I need to create a dataset of images for machine learning and I don't see any better way of converting all of the data to images to feed into the neural network. But if you have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: If you have sufficient memory, just load all of them at once. Otherwise read them from the hard disk using a generator or some sorts. To speed up access put your files onto an SSD. Depending on your ML library of choice it might already have efficient facilities to load image data from files.